# Reading struct from binary file doesn't show it as it should

Tags: file, struct, binary

I have populated a structure with data and wrote it into a binary file. The problem is, when I try to read it back, it doesn't show the structure correctly! Here's the code...

```
#define MAXS 30
 typedef struct {
    char  id[50];
    int pct1, pct2;
    } TStudd;

int ReadStruct(FILE* f, TStudd as ){
 int i=0;
 while (i < MAXS && fscanf(f, "%s" , as.id) == 1) 
 {
     fscanf (f, "%i %i", &as.pct1, &as.pct2);
     i++;
     } 
return i;//total number of read people
}

int WriteBinary(FILE* f, TStudd as){
 int pct1, pct2, i;
 pct1 = as.pct1;
 pct2 = as.pct2;
 i = fwrite(as.id, sizeof(as.id), 1,f);
 if( i != 1) return -1;
 i = fwrite(&pct1, sizeof(pct1), 1,f);
 if( i != 1) return -2;
 i = fwrite(&pct2, sizeof(pct2), 1,f);
 if( i != 1) return -3;
 return 0;
 }

int ReadBinary(FILE* f){
 char  id [50];
 int pct1, pct2, i;
 i = fread(id, sizeof(id), 1,f);
 if( i != 1) return -1;
 printf("%s", id);
 i = fread(&pct1, sizeof(pct1), 1,f);
 if( i != 1) return -2;
 printf("%i", pct1);
 i = fread(&pct2, sizeof(pct2), 1,f);
 if( i != 1) return -3;
 printf("%i", pct2);
 return 0;
 }

 g = fopen(sursa, "rt");

   v = ReadStruct(g, ps);
 printf("%i\n", v);
 f = fopen(dest, "w+b");

}
if ( ReadBinary(f, ps) < 0){
   printf("Eroare scriere\n");
   return 1;
   }
if ( WriteBinary(f) < 0 ){
   printf("Eroare citire\n");
   return 1;
   };
  fclose(g);
 fclose(f);
```

What should I change? Thank you!
Platform is Windows 7 64 bit and the file isn't subject to any conversion (just writing and reading stuff from it)

Comment: What platform are you on?  Where is the open call?  In particular, is the file subject to any text conversions?

Comment: I don't have enough space to post the main here (well, the last lines of it at least), but it is called correctly...

Comment: Main thing is that the open calls specify binary mode

Comment: Trimmed as much as I could. I hope it is not confusing

Comment: Try an fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET) between the fwrite and fread?  Just a guess though.   Either that or close the file between the operations.